# Keras Sequential model fit Vectorizer shape

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to train a model with the following code. Any help to understand what is going on with the shape is appreciated.

```
'' split the sample '''
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(csvFile['Tweet'], csvFile['sent_score'], test_size= 0.20, random_state=1000)
'''add layers to define the input dimension of our feature vectors'''

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(X_train)
X_train = vectorizer.transform(X_train)
X_test  = vectorizer.transform(X_test)

model = Sequential()
#model.add(Reshape((X_train.shape[1],1)))
#model.add(layers.Dense(10, input_dim=(X_train.shape[1],1), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


''' specifies the optimizer and the loss function '''
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

X_train = np.asarray(X_train)
y_train = np.asarray(y_train)

''' fit the model '''
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 212, in <module>
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10)#, verbose=False, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size=10)
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 952, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 751, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/Users/delalma/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 128, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape ()
```

X_test:

```
  (0, 5846) 1
  (0, 6091) 1
  (0, 6921) 1
  (0, 7450) 1
  (0, 7682) 1
  (0, 8581) 1
  (0, 9885) 1
  (0, 13119)    1
  (0, 21322)    1
  (0, 21816)    1
  (0, 23101)    1
```

y_test:

```
9183    -1
16444    1
12410    1
7879     1
17775    1
        ..
15611    1
3776     1
6215    -1
4695     1
9651     1
Name: sent_score, Length: 23136, dtype: int64
```

I understand that the shape needs to be 2 dimensional array but the vectorized X_test return a shape () and I don't know how to handle this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here a complete working example

```
X_train = ['hello adsa sdajka', 'sadk asoa nasdl', 'adk dsao dsak ksasad']
X_test = ['sajjk hello dlsl sdajka', 'daskk sadk']

y_train = [0,1,1]
y_test = [1,0]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(X_train)
X_train = vectorizer.transform(X_train).toarray() # remember toarray()
X_test  = vectorizer.transform(X_test).toarray() # remember toarray()

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(10, input_dim=X_train.shape[-1], activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

y_train = np.asarray(y_train)
y_test = np.asarray(y_test)

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10)
```

your neural network receives an array of dim (n_sample, n_features). the input dim is equal to n_features. with countvectorizer the features are simply a matrix of token counts so the dim is (n_sample, n_word of train).